# How to remove the protocol and domain from a url string?

Tags: php, url, substring, url-parsing, texttrimming

I am running the following code in PHP. My intention is to get "contact.html" in the response, but what I actually get in the output is `ntact.html`

```
$str = 'http://localhost/contact.html';
echo $str . "<br>";
echo ltrim($str,'http://localhost');
```

Any thoughts why PHP is behaving this way and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Earlier related page: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4517067/2943403

Answer (score 6):

`ltrim` doesn't do what you think it does. 
It uses a character collection, so all characters within are deleted.
You should delete the substring using `str_replace`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$str = 'http://localhost/contact.html';
echo $str . "<br>";
echo str_replace('http://localhost/', '', $str);
```

Output:

```
http://localhost/contact.html
contact.html
```

I do realize that you're trying to only replace a string that's at the beginning of your string, but if you have an http://localhost later in your string, you might have bigger problems.

Documentation on ltrim: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php (The Hello World example should be enlightening on explaining exactly what ltrim is doing)

Another example of ltrim misuse: 
[PHP ltrim behavior with character list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050917/php-ltrim-behavior-with-character-list)

Answer (score 3):

Other answers explain why `ltrim` isn't doing what you thought it would, but there's probably a better tool for this job.

Your string is a URL. [PHP has a built-in function to handle those neatly.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
echo parse_url($str, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

(`parse_url` does return the path with a leading slash. If you need to remove that, *then* `ltrim` will work just fine since you'll only trimming one character.)

Answer (score 2):

From the manual on `ltrim()` (emphasis mine):

> You can also specify the characters you want to strip, by means of the character_mask parameter. **Simply list all characters that you want to be stripped**. With `..` you can specify a range of characters.

That means that you list a set of characters to be removed, not a word/string. Here's an example.

```
$str = "foo";
echo ltrim($str, "for"); // Removes everything, because it encounters an F, then two O, outputs ""
echo ltrim($str, "f"); // Removes F only, outputs "oo"
echo ltrim($str, "o"); // Removes nothing, outputs "foo"
```

That means that any character listed in the character mask would be removed. Instead, you can remove the beginning of the string by `str_replace()`, by replacing `http://localhost` with an empty string.

```
$str = 'http://localhost/contact.html';
echo $str . "<br>";
echo str_replace('http://localhost', '', $str);
```

- [**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/rZSAj)
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 1):

ltrim works up there is no match in your `character_mask` which in your case `http://localhost` .

The output will be like this `ntact.html`  why ?

It will match  `http://localhost` and after that there is `/` it will remove it because it is in character mask and so on.

why stopped at `n` because it is not in your charter mask.

So , ltrim will continue remove unless there is no match in character mask

```
$str = 'http://localhost/contact.html';
echo  ltrim($str, 'http');// output ://localhost/contact.html
```

and here i will add only one in mask `/` and it will remove both `//`

```
$str = 'http://localhost/contact.html';
echo  ltrim($str, 'http:/');// output localhost/contact.html
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `ltrim()` is used for stripping whitespaces from the beginning of a string. [See documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php).

If you want to take the string after `http://localhost/` you can use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$str = 'http://localhost/contact.html';
echo $str . "<br>";
echo substr($str,18); // 18 is the length + 1 of http://localhost/
```